# Prevent crawler that doesn't honoring robots.txt

Tags: robots.txt, search-engine-indexing, web-crawlers

I have some problem, when I try to write robots.txt for my site ...

I find some issues by search on Google, and tell me about honor and not honoring `robots.txt`, how I can prevent it, can I perform it with `.htaccess` or other way ?

Comment: This question has an .htaccess file you can use http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/29883/need-to-stop-bots-from-killing-my-webserver

Comment: I would like to see your robot file first,It would not be appropriate to give a one sided decision without invigilating the second side.

Comment: No it's appropriate. They want to prevent a robot that doesn't honor robots.txt. Pretty simple if the robot isn't following your rules, band the sob by IP and cross your fingers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are crawlers not following your robots.txt rules you will need to ban them by IP. Placing their user agent's into your robots.txt to ban does nothing if they aren't following it's rules.

Answer (score 0):

Simple: Ban them all! With PHP and Regex. For example:

```
if (preg_match('/(?i)badbot1|badbot2|badbot3/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){ 

header ('HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'); 
exit(); 
}
```

The header statement is optional

Be careful, never close the last "badbot" with a pipe "|". If you do, you ban all your traffic!
So, use "badbot1|badbot2|badbot3".

Never "|badbot1|badbot2|badbot3" and 
Never "badbot1|badbot2|badbot3|"

Good luck